# 'sys is undefined' error on remote server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have searched SO for relevant posts but unable to find a working solution.

To simplify the issue, I have a default.aspx with with scriptmanager, as follows

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods=true></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    This is a test page with AJAX functionality. This page has script manager.
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I do have following line just below page header:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

I am getting 'sys is undefined' ONLY ON REMOTE SERVER. Local site works fine. The hosting company has confirmed that the .net framework I am targetting (3.5) is correct. I have also tried tweaking web.config as per suggestions in various posts. I doubt the issue lies with web.config.

Live page can be viewed here: http://popinevent.com/

Comment: The URL pointing to `WebResource.axd` returns a 404, that's probably your problem

Answer (score 0):

@Pekka - Thanks, you are right, I can see following in firebug

```
http://popinevent.com/WebResource.axd?d=4IQP1Pagj8. . .  **404 not found**
```

However, there is no file like http://popinevent.com/WebResource.axd. I assume it will be populated automatically at runtime.

Could it be due to AXD not being mapped with IIS, so IIS is actually not able to see this file.

Comment: Sorry for putting this is as answer, it should have been the comment. I am getting used to SO.